# How to create a dynamic selection field in Odoo?

Tags: python, odoo, python-3.8

I was trying to create a dynamic selection field based on conditions

```
x_material_orientation = fields.Selection(selection='_product_customer_uom_change',string='Material Orientation')

def _product_customer_uom_change(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.x_order_customer_uom.name == 'sht':
                return [('sheetfaceup','Sheets Face Up'),('sheetfacedown','Sheets Face Down')]
               
            elif rec.x_order_customer_uom.name == 'yds':
                return [('windfaceout','Wind Face Out'),('windfacein','Wind Face In')]
```

This would work this way? It is not working as of now.
Any suggestion would be of great help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_product_customer_uom_change` is called before current record is loaded, so you cannot use current record to calculate selection field.

You could use context (but `active_id` still won't be available) and pass some information from the previous view, e.g.:

```
def _product_customer_uom_change(self):
    if self.env.context.get('order_type') == 'sht':
        return [('sheetfaceup','Sheets Face Up'),('sheetfacedown','Sheets Face Down')]
           
    elif self.env.context.get('order_type') == 'yds':
        return [('windfaceout','Wind Face Out'),('windfacein','Wind Face In')]
```

If you're not able to this, you should use many2one field (with widget="selection" or create=False) with domain in a view.

(answer written based on experience with Odoo 10)